# Azure devops VSTS query : PBIs planned

Tags: vsts

alguno de casualidad sabe que propiedad podria usar para saber que PBI's he planeado dentro de un sprint, la fecha de creacion no me vale, porque pueden haber estado ya creadas de tiempo atras, Se que en un diagrama de velocidad es posible verlas, pero no se como VSTS determina eso y necesito reproducir un query similar

Answer (score 0):

Se puede usar **Iteration Path** y allí puedes seleccionar el sprint que quieras

[image: ejemplo]